# How to deactivate a NixOS component in OSX?

Tags: macos, nixos

I have trouble using gcc in OSX.

I want to the gcc that comes with XCode (`Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)`). However on my PATH this gcc (`gcc (GCC) 7.4.0`) is taken precedent.

```
$ which gcc
/Users/antkong/.nix-profile/bin/gcc
```

Is there anyway I can turn off/deactivate this particular package? I have checked the documentation but the main commands such as `nix-env`, `nix-store` etc do not offer any escape hatch.

I tried the following

```
$ nix-env -u gcc
warning: name collision in input Nix expressions, skipping '/Users/antkong/.nix-defexpr/channels_root/nixpkgs'
```

but `gcc` still points to the one under my nix profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to use is actually

```
 nix-env -e gcc
```

`-u` is not uninstall as I thought... It actually means `upgrade`.